# Windows firewall blocking ICMP port unreachable?

Tags: c#, udp, windows-firewall

I'm attempting to determine whether or not a remote host is listening on a particular UDP port number.  I do this (in C#) as follows:

```
 Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
  int sent = socket.SendTo(bufsend, bufsend.Length, SocketFlags.None, endpoint);
  int recv = socket.ReceiveFrom(bufrecv, ref endpoint);
```

If no one is listening, I get an ICMP "port unreachable" which is reported on the receive as a socket exception with ErrorCode WSAECONNRESET (10054).  All that makes sense, BUT it only happens when the Windows firewall is disabled.  If the firewall is enabled -- even if I make an exception for the program -- I get ErrorCode WSAETIMEDOUT (10060), presumably because the firewall has eaten the ICMP "port unreachable".

Any suggestions?  I've examined the firewall "advanced security" settings, but to no avail.

Thanks...

Comment: It's possible to fix this issue with a custom rule in the Windows Firewall that opens the firewall to ICMP "destination unreachable" messages ("port unreachable" is a kind of "destination unreachable" - type 3, code 3).  But to do this you must apply the rule to ALL programs, not just to the executable that implements the SendTo / ReceiveFrom test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comment above. You must apply the rule opening the firewall to "destination unreachable" messages to ALL programs, not just to the executable that implements the SendTo / ReceiveFrom test.